# Must I use a private Docker registry to keep my source private?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've just started playing around with Docker recently and wondered if I don't plan to make my code public, does that mean I will have to pay for a private Docker registry?

The reason I'm asking is because it seems like, from the tutorials I'm following, when deploying my container to production, I will have to somehow pull it from the Docker registry. Unless I can push a container directly from my local computer to production, I've to first push my container to the public Docker registry. However, my container often already have a copy of my source which was copied from the volume on my dev machine. So I may not want to make every source code public on the registry.

In this sense, does it mean I'll definitely have to pay to use Docker if I don't wish to make my source code public? Can I push a container directly from my local computer to a production server without going through Docker registry? Or am I using Docker the wrong way?

Comment: You can also run your own docker registry.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to push the image to a public registry such as Dockerhub. You can deploy you own docker registry (which is it self packaged in a docker container) and use that private registry to push and pull images.

The deployment process for the registry can be found in the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/).

Alternatively, you can package your image as a tar ball, upload the tarball to production server, import the tarball back to a docker image and start the container.

```
docker save --output image.tar IMAGE // save the image into a tar ball
docker import image.tar IMAGE // on another server, import the image back from tar.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your own "private" docker registry and dont't have to pay. 
Here is a good tutorial for this solution:
[Setting up a private docker registry.](http://ralph.soika.com/how-to-setup-a-private-docker-registry/)

Little Overview of the steps:

1. Run the Docker Registry Image (registry:2)
2. Create a Self Signed Certificate
3. Run the Private Docker Registry with TLS
4. Access the Remote Registry form a local Client

Now you can pull and push your images to the private registry.

Answer (score 0):

For most languages (except for maybe bash and other scripts :) ) you don't have to add your source code but only the binaries.

Other than that you can store your images locally / on a usb stick with docker export or docker save.

But if you want to pull images from the internet you either go public or have to have a private registry.